# Change dtype of coordinates NetCDF

Tags: python, netcdf, numpy, xarray

I was wondering how to change the dtype from float32 to float64 of coordinates.

I can run the following code in the terminal

```py
ncap2 -s 'lat=double(lat); lon=double(lon)' infile.nc outfile.nc
```

How ever when I try the following command in Python I just get error regarding too many input files.

```py
nco.ncap2(input='infile.nc', output='outfile.nc', 
options=['-s','lat=doubel(lat);  lon=double(lon);'])
```

also tried with ncatted2

```py
nco.ncatted(input='infile.nc', output='out.nc', 
options=['-s','lat=doubel(lat);  lon=double(lon);'])
```

This one just compiles without doing anything.